# ClassNotFoundException While deploying the Java EE application on GlassFish 5.0 Server

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, glassfish, jsr354

During deployment of a Java EE 7 application packaged in a WAR with a minimal entity

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    private Long id;
    @Basic
    @Column(length=8192)
    private CurrencyUnit currencyUnit;

    public MyEntity() {
    }

    public MyEntity(Long id, CurrencyUnit currentyUnit) {
        this.id = id;
        this.currencyUnit = currentyUnit;
    }

    [getter and setter for id and currentyUnit]
```

and a minimal EJB with interface

```
@Local
public interface InitService {

    MyEntity init();
}
```

and implementation

```
@Stateless
public class DefaultInitService implements InitService {

    @Override
    public MyEntity init() {
        MyEntity retValue = new MyEntity(1L, Monetary.getCurrency("EUR"));
        return retValue;
    }
}
```

and a backing bean

```
@Named
@ApplicationScoped
@Eager
public class MyManagedBean {
    @EJB
    private InitService initService;
    private MyEntity myEntity;

    public MyManagedBean() {
    }

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        this.myEntity = initService.init();
    }

    public MyEntity getMyEntity() {
        return myEntity;
    }

    public void setMyEntity(MyEntity myEntity) {
        this.myEntity = myEntity;
    }
}
```

I get the following exception during deployment on GlassFish 5.0:

```
Schwerwiegend:   Undeployment failed for context /monteta-clazz-not-found-issue
Schwerwiegend:   Exception while loading the app : CDI deployment failure:Error instantiating :org.hibernate.validator.cdi.internal.ValidationExtension
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: Error instantiating :org.hibernate.validator.cdi.internal.ValidationExtension
    at org.jboss.weld.util.ServiceLoader.createInstance(ServiceLoader.java:315)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.ServiceLoader.prepareInstance(ServiceLoader.java:247)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.ServiceLoader.loadService(ServiceLoader.java:215)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.ServiceLoader.loadServiceFile(ServiceLoader.java:185)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.ServiceLoader.reload(ServiceLoader.java:165)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.ServiceLoader.iterator(ServiceLoader.java:289)
    at org.glassfish.weld.DeploymentImpl.getExtensions(DeploymentImpl.java:466)
    at org.glassfish.weld.WeldDeployer.event(WeldDeployer.java:223)
    at org.glassfish.kernel.event.EventsImpl.send(EventsImpl.java:131)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.load(ApplicationInfo.java:328)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:496)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:540)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:536)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:566)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:558)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1465)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:110)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1847)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1723)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:190)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:463)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:242)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:539)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:593)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:573)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.ServiceLoader.createInstance(ServiceLoader.java:313)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type javax.money.MonetaryAmount not present
    at sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:117)
    at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:125)
    at sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.reifyTypeArguments(Reifier.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:138)
    at sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.generics.repository.ClassRepository.getSuperInterfaces(ClassRepository.java:108)
    at java.lang.Class.getGenericInterfaces(Class.java:913)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.TypeHelper.resolveTypeForClassAndHierarchy(TypeHelper.java:390)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.TypeHelper.resolveTypes(TypeHelper.java:351)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.TypeHelper.extractType(TypeHelper.java:327)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ClassBasedValidatorDescriptor.<init>(ClassBasedValidatorDescriptor.java:39)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintValidatorDescriptor.forClass(ConstraintValidatorDescriptor.java:49)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.core.ConstraintHelper.putConstraints(ConstraintHelper.java:686)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.core.ConstraintHelper.<init>(ConstraintHelper.java:318)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorFactoryImpl.<init>(ValidatorFactoryImpl.java:155)
    at org.hibernate.validator.HibernateValidator.buildValidatorFactory(HibernateValidator.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl.buildValidatorFactory(ConfigurationImpl.java:322)
    at org.hibernate.validator.cdi.internal.ValidationExtension.<init>(ValidationExtension.java:116)
    ... 53 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.money.MonetaryAmount
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ExtensionManager$ExtensionManagerWiring.getClassByDelegation(ExtensionManager.java:873)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.searchImports(BundleWiringImpl.java:1553)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1484)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$400(BundleWiringImpl.java:75)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:1955)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:114)
    ... 78 more
```

The missing type is provided in

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.money</groupId>
    <artifactId>money-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.javamoney</groupId>
    <artifactId>moneta</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

A MCVE is available at https://gitlab.com/krichter/monteta-clazz-not-found-issue.

Comment: A workaround is to use Money instead of floating point + CurrencyUnit which required me to change larger parts of my application and makes the encounter a bunch of other issues with moneta - of course -, but this ClassNotFoundException makes is really odd.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have incorrect version of `org.javamoney:moneta:1.0.1-SNAPSHOT`. The `SNAPSHOT` dependency is for developers only but never published to Maven Repository.
You can check [all available versions in Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.javamoney%22%20AND%20a%3A%22moneta%22)

So, to fix just try to use this one:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.javamoney</groupId>
    <artifactId>moneta</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: no, sorry I haven't time for this atm. My suggestion doesn't help for you?

Comment: Thanks for you input. I tried your solution and it didn't help. Sorry for my (deleted) fast, unreflected reaction. I started [a discussion about the necessity of answerers trying their solutions on MCVE before posting an answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361868/how-to-better-deal-with-answers-ignoring-mcve-in-question?noredirect=1#comment547859_361868) which made me realize that I should have valued your answer better. Nothing was directed against you - in case you wonder.

Answer (score 0):

For me the workaround "Money instead of floating point + CurrencyUnit" wasn't an option because even if i suppressed my classes using java.money the error was still present. Also If i removed hibernate validator from my dependencies and if i excluded it from transitives the error remains.

This way i understood the library was already present in glassfish classpath. As it was not an easy solution for me to remove it from there, and as i also needed to use java.money in my app i thought i can just add java.money in the glassfish classpath and it worked. I think its because of glassfish "[delegates](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26576_01/doc.312/e24930/class-loaders.htm#GSDVG00095)" classloader method which makes the app class loader to delegate to the server classloaders for loading of all the classes the server can load.

So the solution was for me to add java.money-api.jar in the lib/endorsed folder of glassfish installation.